# Cannot be referenced from a static function?

Tags: java

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;

public class LootGenerator{

public static void main (String[] args)
    throws FileNotFoundException{
        System.out.println("This program simulates the random item generator");
        System.out.println("from the game Diablo II.  Happy hunting!");
        System.out.println();
        String file="monstats.txt";
        Monster[] array = getArray(file);
        //Monster alex=getRandomMonster(array);
        }

public Monster getRandomMonster(Monster[] array){
  int randMonster = (int)(Math.random() * array.length);
    return array[randMonster];
}

public Monster[] getArray (String file)
    throws FileNotFoundException{
Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File (file));
Monster[] array = new Monster[sc.nextInt()];
sc.next(); //takes away the word Class
sc.next(); //takes away the word Type
sc.next(); //takes away the word Level
sc.next(); //takes away the word TreasureClass
for(int a = 0; a < array.length; a++)
{
    array[a] = new Monster(sc.next(), sc.next(), sc.nextInt(), sc.next());
}
return array;
}

}

  class Monster{
    private String monsterClass;
private String type;
    private int level;
    private String treasureClass;

public Monster(String myClass, String myType, int myLevel, String myTreasureClass){
    monsterClass = myClass;
      type = myType;
    level = myLevel;
    treasureClass = myTreasureClass;
}

public String getMonsterClass(){
    return monsterClass;
}

public String getType(){
    return type;
}

public int getLevel(){
    return level;
}

public String getTreasureClass(){
    return treasureClass;
}
```

}

I can't figure out what is wrong with my program...any advice? I keep getting that it can't be referenced from a static context - the line Monster[] array = getArray(file) that is. The object of the program is to randomly generate a monster from a text file - the assignment is here if you need to look at the text file itself: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis110/hw/hw06/index.html

Comment: you can't reference instance methods from static methods, ... getArray is not declared static

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to call a regular method from a static method, which isn't possible. You could instantiate LootGenerator and then call the method or make the method static (simply add the static modifier to the method).

One solution:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
    throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("This program simulates the random item generator");
        System.out.println("from the game Diablo II.  Happy hunting!");
        System.out.println();
        String file = "monstats.txt";
        LootGenerator lg = new LootGenerator();
        Monster[] array = lg.getArray(file);
        Monster alex = lg.getRandomMonster(array);
}
```

You can find more information about instance and class members [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

In short, instance methods can only be called on instances of a class. Static methods belong to the class and can be  called from anywhere, but they can't access instance variables or call instance methods unless they actually have a reference to an instance of a class.

Answer (score 2):

get array is not static method, you need to initiate a object or to make it static

Answer (score 1):

`getArray` is an instance method, and you're calling it from `main` which is declared as `static`. If you change `getArray` to be static it'll compile.

You'll also have the same problem with `getRandomMonster`.

Answer (score 1):

You should make

```
public Monster[] getArray (String file)
    throws FileNotFoundException
```

static so that you can call it from inside `main()` as you are doing currently , you dont need to instantiate the class `LootGenerator` to call it (if the method is static, it belongs to the class where it is declared and can be called without using any instance of that class).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference a non-static method (`getArray`) which is related to a specific object directly from a static method (`main`), which is not related to a specific object.

To fix it, you may simply change your method to static:

```
public static Monster[] getArray (String file) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getArray()` and `getRandomMonster()` are non-static - they need an instance of your object to be called on. Your main method is static, so you don't have an instance. You have to create it:

```
LootGenerator generator = new LootGenerator();
generator.getArray(..);
generator.getRandomMonster(..);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `main` function is `static`, meaning that it can be called on the class as a whole, not just a particular instance of that class.  `getArray` is not defined as static, so if you call it you have to call it on a particular instance of a `LootGenerator`, but you're trying to call it on the class as a whole.  I don't see any non-static code in `getArray`, so you should be able to just declare it static.