# Static methods and variables

Tags: java, static, static-methods, static-members

I do know that in java static methods can only use static variables and static methods and but non static methods can use non static variables and methods. is there any explanation why static methods can only access static variables/methods? and cannot access non static methods and variables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot be referenced from a static function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029845/cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-function)

Comment: it's not a duplicate, the contents of my question is completely different.

Comment: The answers to that question apply equally well to this question.

Comment: But you meant duplicate, duplicate is different from "answer" you could have said, "The answer here in this link will apply equally well to this question" rather than saying it's a duplicate, it's a bit misleading

Comment: The "possible duplicate of (link)" text is automatically added by the system when a duplicate is identified by a user. Please understand that the goal of Stack Overflow is to provide the best *answers*, whether they are new answers or links to previously given answers. Duplicate identification helps others who search for similar questions later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

to access non-static methods/fields, you require an instance of the class.

Comment: But the OP wants to know *why*.  Is this some arbitrary rule, or is there a reason?  It behooves us to explain "yes, there is a very important reason".  IMHO...

Comment: If one understands what `static` actually means (instead of just learning the rules), then the reason should be obvious.

Answer (score 3):

When you instantiate a class, it will be loaded into a heap or stack. In this case your application has references to those parts of memory instances are located. However, static methods are just functions loaded into the memory. That is why if your static method wants to access a class variable or method it cannot just call it because there may be multiple references to that class in the heap contrary to one and only one static method can exist.

If you want to call any non-static method from a static method, you should use the instance (or create one) to that class so that you can define which class reference you really mean.

Answer (score 2):

Think about it:

a) Suppose you were a static method.

b) You exist independently of any object instance. You exist even if there's NO class instance.

c) You want to access a non-static variable.  A variable that exists in ONE and ONLY one object instance - a variable that's SPECIFIC to THAT PARTICULAR object instance.

d) Which object instance's non-static variable are you going to use???

Static methods MAY access non-static members of classes... provided they do it through a class reference.

Otherwise - no class reference - no access.

Make sense? ;)

Comment: soo it means is thre's no class reference, I cannot access that instance variable? am i right?

Answer (score 0):

In the Static context 'this' keyword is not accessible . we cannot use this keyword in the static context . Instance variables are initialized when the constructor invokes. But static variables are initialized when the class loads. during the loading of the class , instance variables are still not identified during this time if we use instance variables in static context it leads to compile time error because they are not identified at that time